# Extra blank records being added to Mysql database on insert

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, rows

On submit, records are being inserted into MySQL database but 4 extra blank rows are being inserted too. The blank rows in phpmyadmin have only the "id" but the other columns in the table are empty/blank. I am attaching my code below. Your help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <style type="text/css" charset="utf-8"/>
        *{background:#eee;padding:2px;box-sizing:border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    $dbhost = 'host';
    $dbuser = 'user';
    $dbpass = 'passw';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    //test if the connection is established successfully then it will proceed in next process else it will throw an error message
    if (!$conn) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db('cato'); //we specify here the Database name we are using


    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($_POST as $val) {
            $business_name = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["business_name"][$i]));
            $business_type = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["business_type"][$i]));
            $country = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["country"][$i]));
            $province = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["province"][$i]));
            $address = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["address"][$i]));
            $postcode = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["postcode"][$i]));
            $telephone1 = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["telephone1"][$i]));
            $telephone2 = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["telephone2"][$i]));
            $category = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["category"][$i]));
            $email = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"][$i]));
            $i++;
            mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO company_details (company_id, business_name, business_type, country, province, address, postcode, telephone1, telephone2, category, email) VALUES ('','$business_name', '$business_type', '$country', '$province', '$address', '$postcode', '$telephone1', '$telephone2', '$category', '$email')");
        }
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Successs!! records have been added to database");
        window.location = "index.php?db=cato";
    </script>

    <?php
    //close of connection
    mysql_close($conn);
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you using : foreach ($_POST as $val) ??

Comment: Because in my form there many entries sharing the same name. for example: <input name=\"business_name[]\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $parsed1[$i]. "\">";

Comment: just remove that foreach loop ..

Comment: I did but then nothing gets inserted at all.

Comment: ok.. is different arrays business_name, business_type, country etc have same number of values ? if so then try  replacing foreach with foreach ($_POST["business_name"] as $val) ..

Comment: Jazak Allah Syed, that worked perfectly! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is f in

```
foreach ($_POST as $val)
```

it not suppose to be there at all (you are trying to execute query for each field)

and use

```
($_POST["business_name"]) instead of ($_POST["business_name"][$i])
```

Comment: Sorry if my question is not too clear, each field I posted above has  value of different values. Like business_name would have more than one value.

Comment: than do it in for loop for($i=0;i<count($_POST["business_name"]);i++) instead of foreach ($_POST as $val) {

Answer (score 1):

Use the following assuming that the HTML field names are same as in the POST

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $business_name = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["business_name"]));
        $business_type = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["business_type"]));
        $country = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["country"]));
        $province = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["province"]));
        $address = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["address"]));
        $postcode = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["postcode"]));
        $telephone1 = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["telephone1"]));
        $telephone2 = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["telephone2"]));
        $category = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["category"]));
        $email = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]));
}
```

Then use the insert query. In other words take out forach $_POST

Answer (score 0):

Remove for loop from your code,

```
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $business_name = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["business_name"][$i]));
            $business_type = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["business_type"][$i]));
            $country = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["country"][$i]));
            $province = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["province"][$i]));
            $address = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["address"][$i]));
            $postcode = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["postcode"][$i]));
            $telephone1 = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["telephone1"][$i]));
            $telephone2 = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["telephone2"][$i]));
            $category = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["category"][$i]));
            $email = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"][$i]));
            mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO company_details (company_id, business_name, business_type, country, province, address, postcode, telephone1, telephone2, category, email) VALUES ('','$business_name', '$business_type', '$country', '$province', '$address', '$postcode', '$telephone1', '$telephone2', '$category', '$email')");
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: I just did that and nothing has been inserted into database.